# How can I Increase pixel In rendering my shader?

Tags: unity, pixel, shaderlab

This is my flow map shader , it works correctly but I have problem In Rendering.
how can I Increase pixels per unit In my shader?

[image: Flow_Map]

```
Shader "Custom/Flow Map"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _FlowMap ("Flow Map", 2D) = "white" {}
        _FlowSpeed ("Flow Speed", float) = 0.05

        [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap ("Pixel snap", Float) = 0
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        { 
            "Queue"="Transparent" 
            "IgnoreProjector"="True" 
            "RenderType"="Transparent" 
            "PreviewType"="Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
        }

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile _ PIXELSNAP_ON
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            fixed4 _Color;

            v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
            {
                v2f OUT;

                OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
                OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
                OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
                #ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
                OUT.vertex = UnityPixelSnap (OUT.vertex);
                #endif

                return OUT;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _FlowMap;
            float _FlowSpeed;

            fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
            {
                float3 flowDir = tex2D(_FlowMap, IN.texcoord) * 2.0f - 1.0f;
                flowDir *= _FlowSpeed;

                float phase0 = frac(_Time[1] * 0.5f + 0.5f);
                float phase1 = frac(_Time[1] * 0.5f + 1.0f);

                half3 tex0 = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord + flowDir.xy * phase0);
                half3 tex1 = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord + flowDir.xy * phase1);

                float flowLerp = abs((0.5f - phase0) / 0.5f);
                half3 finalColor = lerp(tex0, tex1, flowLerp);

                fixed4 c = float4(finalColor, 1.0f) * IN.color;
                c.rgb *= c.a;
                return c;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: Why does your shader need to increase the PPU? why not just change it on the texture itself?